# hourly cron job runs fine except at midnight

Tags: cron, postgresql

I have a cron job which is set to run hourly using `0 * * * *`. The command is to run a postgres query and output to a file:

```
0 * * * * psql foo -f /home/foo/stats.sql >> /home/foo/stats.txt
```

This is the `foo` user's crontab, and `foo` has access to the database.

The tasks runs successfully every hour. It logs `now()` at the top of each entry and the result of the query. Except at midnight. There's an entry every hour from 01:00 to 23:00 but never at 00:00.

What's odd is that the cron job actually runs at midnight. You can see it in syslog:

```
Jul  9 00:00:01 hostname CRON[24315]: (foo) CMD (psql foo -f /home/foo/stats.sql >> /home/foo/stats.txt)
```

It never outputs anything to the file. There's no error in syslog, no indication anything went wrong, just no midnight entry in the output file.

I'm on Debian Stretch.

Comment: Change the 0 to */1 which is always true every hour.

Comment: @Dougie This would run the command every minute (same as `* * * * *`). The current setting should be fine.

Comment: * */1 * * * should go hourly @Freddy